# Selenium - How to get the attributes of two HTML nodes at once in Java?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a program for hours now, any I am totaly confused. So the deal is that I want to make a steam price lister. Here is the [website](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730#p1_price_desc).

Let's say I want to list the two highest priced item's name and it's price. If you look at the html source you will see that the first 2 found item are named like this:

```
id=result_0_name
id=result_1_name
```

But inside the result 0 and result 1 the price just called: "market_table_value"

And I am trying to print out like this:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("result_0_name"))).getAttribute("market_table_value");
```

But then I realised that the program won't recognise that I want the "result0"'s price, maybe it will always give me a static number, because there is no unique number for the market value.

Sorry if I confused you guys, but I really hope that you will understand me, because my mind got blown up, and I have no idea how to do it :/

Comment: You want to build a crawler to get the content of the Steam site?

Comment: i want to build a stock listener, i don't want to cheat, i just want to list some item for myself

Comment: Steam site should have an api, no ?

Comment: no they don't have, because "its illegal" in their tems, but come on, it's not an auto-purchase bot i just want to see through the items more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use xPath here:

- Get item name: `//*[@id="result_0_name"]`
- Get item price: `//*[@id="result_0"]/div[1]/span[1]/span`

**Java code**

```
public class Item {
     private String name;
     private String price;

     public Item(String name, String price) {
        this.name=name;
        this.price=price;
     }

     public String getName() {
        return name;
     }

     public String getPrice() {
        return price;
     }
}

/**
 *
 * Get item at position {@code position} or {@code null} if not found.
 *
 */
private Item getHighestItem(int position, WebDriver driver) {
   Item item=null;

   try {
      int index = position-1;
      String name = driver.findElement(By.xPath("//*[@id='result_" + index + "_name']")).getText();
      String price = driver.findElement(By.xPath("//*[@id='result_" + index + "']/div[1]/span[1]/span")).getText();

      item = new Item(name, price);
   } catch(NoSuchElementException nse) {
       // handle exception here...
   }

   return item;
}
```

**Sample usage**

```
WebDriver driver = ...;
...
Item firstItem = getHighestItem(1, driver); // get Most expensive item 
Item secondItem = getHighestItem(2, driver); // get 2nd Most expensive item
...
```